# MacBook Pro won't boot. Ideas?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, startup

MacBook Pro won't boot. Getting various grey screens. When try to do straight boot, get flashing folder.

Other things not working: OS X recovery, start up manager, single user mode, verbose mode, safe mode. Will go to Internet recovery, enter password, stall (-2002F- error).

Tried resetting NVRAM and SMC, but nothing.

Tried with new hard drive, but exact same results with old hard drive (I thought old hard drive might be corrupted, so got new one, but getting identical results).

Any ideas? Could go to Apple service centre, but closest to where I am is 3 hours drive.

Should note, that many attempts ago Mac booted fine (by some divine intervention I think), so backed up everything right away, but after using computer as usual for an hour (mostly Internet browsing using both Safari and Chrome), computer slowed down to snail pace, so tried rebooting but again got results as listed above.

Any help or ideas greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That error means it failed to connect to the network. Is your network perchance WPA or WPA2/WPA mixed with a password? [Apparently Internet Recovery doesn't play well with those](https://discussions.apple.com/message/18708341#18708341) ([another link](http://www.mac-forums.com/os-x-operating-system/299543-macbook-air-internet-recovery-error.html)).

Did that new hard drive have OS X installed or not? If not, it wouldn't be able to boot for obvious reasons. Just to make sure.

[Have you tried creating a bootable version of Apple Hardware Test?](https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest)

Comment: I think my problem is with a faulty SATA cable. But this is also very helpful and good to know. Thanks!